# Crawlability of actions with HttpPost attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, search, seo, web-crawler

The technology used is ASP.NET MVC 4.

Are the search engines able to crawl actions which have HttpPost attribute?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes the Googlebot is able to perform POST-Request. ( See: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.de/2011/11/get-post-and-safely-surfacing-more-of.html ) But you should not count on it. For me it's just unpredictable which forms are submitted and which are not.

My advice: Ensure that every single URL with ranking potential is reachable via GET-Requests. That might also help you to control indexation via robots.txt